# jQuery: how to get to the parent children values in a loop

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to write a row to a table for each `.shoppingCart_Category` with cells corresponding to the values of these child elements:

- `.brennansLineShoppingCart`
- `.shoppingCart_qty-select`
- `.shoppingCart_Price_Each`
- `.shoppingCart_Price_Each`

The output should be:

```
Item                    QTY Each    Price
Box #01 - On Wisconsin  1   $26.99  $26.99
Box #01 - On Wisconsin  1   $26.99  $26.99
Box #01 - On Wisconsin  1   $26.99  $26.99
Box #05 - On Wisconsin  1   $32.85  $32.85
Box #05 - On Wisconsin  1   $32.85  $32.85
```

My code snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $.each($('.shipToMultipleSection, .shoppingCart_Category, .shoppingCart_qtyArea, .shoppingCartPrice'), function () {
    var h = '<tr class="multiLine">';
    h += '<td>' + $(this).parent('.brennansLineShoppingCart').html() + '</td>';     
    h += '<td>' + $(this).parent.('.shoppingCart_qty-select').find('option').html() + '</td>';
    h += '<td>' + $('.shoppingCart_Price_Each').html().replace(/Each/, "") + '</td>';
    h += '<td>' + $('.shoppingCart_SubTotal_Each').html().replace(/Price/, "") + '</td>';
    h += '</tr>';
    $(".tableOrderPreviewTotals tr:last").after(h);
   });
 });
```

```css
.tableOrderPreviewTotals td {
    border: solid 1px #888;
}
hr {
    width:100%;
    height:1px;
    background: #ddd
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="shipToMultipleSection">
    <div class="shoppingCart_Category">
        <div class="shoppingCart_qtyArea">
            <div class="shoppingCart_qtyLabel">QTY</div>
            <select class="shoppingCart_qty-select">
                <option value="1">1</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="brennansLineShoppingCart">Box #01 - On Wisconsin</div>
        <div class="shoppingCartPrice">
            <div class="shoppingCart_Price_Each">Each $26.99</div>
            <div class="shoppingCart_SubTotal_Each">Price $26.99</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div class="shoppingCart_Category">
        <div class="shoppingCart_qtyArea">
            <div class="shoppingCart_qtyLabel">QTY</div>
            <select class="shoppingCart_qty-select">
                <option value="1">1</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="brennansLineShoppingCart">Box #01 - On Wisconsin</div>
        <div class="shoppingCartPrice">
            <div class="shoppingCart_Price_Each">Each $26.99</div>
            <div class="shoppingCart_SubTotal_Each">Price $26.99</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div class="shoppingCart_Category">
        <div class="shoppingCart_qtyArea">
            <div class="shoppingCart_qtyLabel">QTY</div>
            <select class="shoppingCart_qty-select">
                <option value="1">1</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="brennansLineShoppingCart">Box #01 - On Wisconsin</div>
        <div class="shoppingCartPrice">
            <div class="shoppingCart_Price_Each">Each $26.99</div>
            <div class="shoppingCart_SubTotal_Each">Price $26.99</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div class="shoppingCart_Category">
        <div class="shoppingCart_qtyArea">
            <div class="shoppingCart_qtyLabel">QTY</div>
            <select class="shoppingCart_qty-select">
                <option value="1">1</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="brennansLineShoppingCart">Box #05 - On Wisconsin</div>
        <div class="shoppingCartPrice">
            <div class="shoppingCart_Price_Each">Each $32.85</div>
            <div class="shoppingCart_SubTotal_Each">Price $32.85</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div class="shoppingCart_Category">
        <div class="shoppingCart_qtyArea">
            <div class="shoppingCart_qtyLabel">QTY</div>
            <select class="shoppingCart_qty-select">
                <option value="1">1</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="brennansLineShoppingCart">Box #05 - On Wisconsin</div>
        <div class="shoppingCartPrice">
            <div class="shoppingCart_Price_Each">Each $32.85</div>
            <div class="shoppingCart_SubTotal_Each">Price $32.85</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr />
</div>
<div class="dividerShoppingcart"></div>
<table class="tableOrderPreviewTotals">
    <tr>
        <td class="yord_hdr">Item</td>
        <td class="yord_hdr_center">QTY</td>
        <td class="yord_hdr_center">Each</td>
        <td class="yord_hdr_center">Price</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I have a jsfiddle for demonstration if you prefer: http://jsfiddle.net/h82ca727/2/

Comment: Well, JS code in fiddle quite differs from the one in question: there are no `.parent()` in fiddle. Which code is supposed to be correct? `parent.('.shoppingCart_qty-select')` is either typo (extra `.` before `(`) or an error.

Comment: I don't have time to offer an explanation of this right now, but here's an updated version of your fiddle which does what I think you want. http://jsfiddle.net/h82ca727/3/ Anyone who has time to explain everything feel free to run with this fiddle.

Comment: Pretty much [the same fiddle from me](http://jsfiddle.net/h82ca727/4/) which is based on first fiddle version. The differance from JAAulde's version is in using string concatenations with single `.append()` instead of multiple `.append()`s (concatenation is supposed to work a little faster) and using `.text()` instead of `.html()` (`.text()` looks more logical in this situation).

Comment: Thank you. Looking at your example I was able to get what I needed. Also thanks for the corrections, I am learning how to format correctly my questions, this is a good example you have given me. I do struggle to be concise and clear. Thank you.